# AWS S3 - Mass Delete Strategy Over 400K Objects

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-java-sdk

I've been looking for a strategy for a few days that contemplates a massive object deletion scenario in S3. Deletions that exceed 400K of objects for example.

I currently have a bucket with a structure similar to the one below:

- **.../FOO/${customerID}/../myObject.ext**
- **.../ACME/${customerID}/../myObject.ext**
- **.../XPTO/${customerID}/../myObject.ext**

That is, for the most part I have a segregation of "folders" by the customerID

I was looking for some solution synchronously, with low latency and with good performance.

I found some solutions using Lifecycle rules policy, but I would have to periodically create dynamic deletion policies for each customer and later delete them

The test bucket is currently versioning disabled (but I can enable it if necessary).

I created a batch delete using the Java SDK, however there are cases where I need to delete more than 400k objects. This ends up being extremely time-consuming.

Any have any suggestions?

Comment: How many different "paths" do you have? Do you have list of customer IDs or paths?

Comment: Thanks for replying @ErmiyaEskandary . I have several "paths". But these paths are segregated by customerID. The deletion is performed by an internal Job that will check which customer will have the data deleted.

Comment: Do you actually care how long it takes? Can you effectively hide these objects from your application at the point you make the decision to delete them (e.g. by suspending a customer's account or deleting the associated customer ID from a database table)?

Comment: @jarmod I need to physically delete all data from a client (including artifacts in S3). This is due to the company's internal compliance.

Comment: Lifecycle rules seem like the most straightforward way to accomplish this goal.  Is there a reason they don't work for you?

Comment: Hi @AnonCoward. The main reason I want to avoid this approach is that I will have "N" Rules for each customer. And I will have to delete these rules periodically. And as far as I could look in the documentation, it's not possible to delete "separate" rules

Answer (score 0):

You'll either need to use a Lifecycle Policy, or you'll need to write your own code to call `DeleteObjects()`.

Each request can contain 1000 keys.

The slow part is listing the objects in the bucket. You might want to use [Amazon S3 Inventory](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/storage-inventory.html), which can provide a daily or weekly CSV file listing all objects. Your program can use the inventory file as input.

400,000 objects would therefore require 400 calls to `DeleteObjects()`.

Alternatively, you can programmatically call `PutObjectLifecycle()` to have S3 do all the deletion for you.

Comment: I've already created a batch delete method, but it's extremely time-consuming. In a test with an average of 10K records it took almost 9 minutes.

I'm currently validating the use of aws s3 CLI. It looks like it's a little faster, but it's still not what I'm really looking for.

I believe that in fact the best strategy would be to use PutObjectLifecycle, as I've exhausted the alternatives.

Comment: If you are sending 1000 objects per `DeleteObjects()` call, and you tested with 10K records, does that mean it took 9 minutes for 10 calls, or about 1 minute per call? If so, it sounds like a good case for multi-threading.